# Can we add a CloudFront behavior based on request header?

Tags: amazon-web-services, header, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Behaviors on Cloud front are based on path. I'm trying to see if there is another way to add behavior based on request header without involving Lambda@Edge?

For example, requests with header 'user-agent'='somecrawler' will be directed to behavior, others will be directed to another behavior.

Answer (score 3):

No, CloudFront cache behaviors only support path-based routing. As you've mentioned, you can use Lambda@Edge, but that's more complicated.